# Trying to understand TypeScript's message regarding my onClick event

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm learning TypeScript with React and it's quite frustrating and picky, but I'm sticking with it.  At the moment, I'm getting a typescript message for my inline onClick and not sure how to handle it.

```
type MenuProps = {
  openMenu: Function;
  toggle: string;
  slidein: string;
};
...
const Menu: FunctionComponent<MenuProps> = ({ openMenu, toggle, slidein }) => {
...
  <div className={`menu ${toggle}`} onClick={openMenu}>
...
```

The message I'm getting is:

```
Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.
  Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>): void'

The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'
```

**Update**

To add to my complexity and brain cramp... these are my remining onClick events that I suppose need different type situations.

```
<div className={`expand ${slidein}`}>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <Link to="/" onClick={openMenu}>
        List
      </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/add-user" onClick={openMenu}>
        Add User
      </Link>
    </li>
    <li>Add Climb</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pointing out that your type definition for the openMenu prop is too broad. They might pass in, for example, a function that expects to receive a number as its first argument, which wouldn't match with what the onClick handler will do. So be more specific like this:

```
import React, { MouseEvent, FunctionComponent } from 'react';

type MenuProps = {
  openMenu: (event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void;
  toggle: string;
  slidein: string;
};
```

Comment: With you solution, I'm getting `Type 'MouseEvent' is not generic`

Comment: Ok, I noticed I needed to add `MouseEvent` to the import list for React, but now I'm getting even more outputs to the issue.

Comment: Looks like when I removed the second `, MouseEvent` from the openMenu property, it fixed that one, but apparently it didn't fix the others.  I'm starting not to like TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks.  I've updated my question with the other two onClick events, which I didn't realize would be separate Type scenarios.

Comment: Assuming those are react-router Link components, then i think the onClick type for them will be `(event: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => void`. MouseEvent has different variations depending on what type of element is the source. And links use `<a>` tags rather than `<div>`s

Comment: If you wanted a type which could work regardless of what the element is, you could do `(event: MouseEvent) => void`. This should work for many cases, but it does lose the ability to enforce what type of element it is. So code that's referencing event.currentTarget can't guarantee exactly what the element is.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!  I'm starting to see the pattern now, but still have a ways to go.